# I can't see marker icons creating a google map by PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps

I have a MySQL table with latitude and longitude coordinates for each row.
Following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=es#createmap) i created a php file that generates this XML code:

```
<markers>
<marker name="Altopascio" anno="b. dal 1991 al 2000" gruppi="Sinti" affollamento="da 26 a 50" lat="10.6744775772094" lng="43.8144836425781" criticita="bassa" lat2="4852647" lng2="1634697"/>
<marker name="Buggiano" anno="a. fino al 1990" gruppi="Rom istriani" affollamento="da 51 a 100" lat="10.7345352172851" lng="43.8763999938964" criticita="nessuna" lat2="4859624" lng2="1639383"/>
<marker name="Carrara - Insediamento di Lavello" anno="a. fino al 1990" gruppi="Rom Ex Iugoslavia" affollamento="da 26 a 50" lat="10.1012363433837" lng="44.0793380737304" criticita="media" lat2="4881291" lng2="1588201"/>
[...]
</markers>
```

Then, still following Google Dev instructions, I've created the map with this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  nessuna: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bassa: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  media: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  alta: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.7639427185058, 11.3140087127685),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("gisajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    //alert(markers.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      //alert(i);
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>";
      var icon = customIcons[criticita] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

I can't understand why I can't see the marker icons on the map.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the load() function called ?

Comment: What happened when you did the steps in "Checking that XML Output Works"? What happens if you change your marker definition to remove the custom icon (comment out the icon and shadow properties)?

Comment: @Kaloyan: is in the body tag.

Comment: `var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;` - where did `address` come from; it's not defined in your code anywhere in the question

Comment: @geocodezip: the XML output works fine, i checked it several times. And also if i comment out all icon properties i can't see markers on the map.

Comment: @duncan: you're right, my mistake. Anyway also deleting it the code still doesn't work :(

Comment: Your map is centered in Florence Italy; your markers are in Somalia.  You can't see them unless you move the map. [your code and markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_xmlparsing_customIcons.html)

Comment: omg, i don't made the db... I didn't checked the coordinates, obv they are wrong. I'm a dumbass. Thank you all!

Comment: You should still accept the answer by @duncan that was definitely a problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the icon to `customIcons[criticita]` but I think that should be `customIcons[markers[i].getAttribute("criticita")]`

Also you do `new google.maps.InfoWindow;` but that should be `new google.maps.InfoWindow();`

Comment: I tried, but markers are still not visible.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?  What do you get if you uncomment `alert(markers.length)` and `alert(i);`?

Comment: markers.length gives me the number of rows in the mysql db (53). Strange thing (i think) on the alert(i);. This one gives me only the first alert (an alert window with "0" inside), but to work accurately it should create 54 different alert windows, right? P.s. no js errors

Comment: @L'Albume, updated my answer with another idea

Comment: changed, still not working... Anyway i just saw in the error console 6/7 errors like this: Data e ora: 02/04/2013 15:16:15
Errore: Image corrupt or truncated: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i69355&2i47480&2e1&3u9&4m2&1u600&2u600&5m3&1e0&2b1&5sit-IT&token=54858
File sorgente: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i69355&2i47480&2e1&3u9&4m2&1u600&2u600&5m3&1e0&2b1&5sit-IT&token=54858
Riga: 0